# ADB mkdir permission denied

Tags: command-line, android, android-sdk, adb, ubuntu-for-android

I am trying to run AVS-SDK (Alexa) SampleApp on an Android Device On UBUNTU.
I have opened two terminals,
in first terminal i am obtaining the root access for the android device using ADB.
Following commands are used ,

```
adb connect <my_device_ipaddress>
adb shell
xu 7411
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

and in second terminal i am building the AVS-SDK SampleApp by using following command

```
sudo bash -x setup.sh config.json -a androidConfig.txt -s 998987
```

The error i am facing while building is ,

```
adb shell mkdir -p /system/repavs/bin
mkdir: '/system/repavs/bin': Permission denied
```

but if i execute the same command in first terminal where i have root access to the android device, it will execute.

My question here is, i am connecting using ADB with root access but still the permission denied error is coming, can anyone guide me solving this issue.
Is there any other way to get the permission or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: Probably means you don't have `write` access to the `/system/revpas` directory

Comment: how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have tried and researched it is not possible , because if the ADB is open in one terminal with root access then only that session with that terminal can access the device with root access, other terminals or any other process wont be able to work in the same session or process.